# Multi canvas layer paint application in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am building a paint tool with eraser option using HTML5 canvas. The canvas loads a backgroung image and on the image users can draw paintings. But on using the eraser tool only the painted part should be erased(not the part of the image). I know that i must use more than one canvas for it. please help me with some code example if you can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Display two canvas at the same position but with different z-index. Let the user interact with the top canvas only (actually, you don't need the bottom canvas, you can use an absolute positioned image or an background-image instead). If you need explicit examples how to work on canvas in general, you should read some resources first.

Comment: Funny, I just built an HTML5 "doodle pad" app myself.  You're right -- use two canvas elements.  Position them absolute and layer them on top of each other.  Apply the background to the canvas context in the back and do all of your drawing on the canvas context in the front.  If you've already got a canvas to draw on, just create another one and point your background editing functions at it instead of the drawing canvas.

Comment: @Zeta +1 for suggesting that the background doesn't need to be a canvas.

Comment: It seems to me that your title is in fact the answer to your question... not that you really have a question other than "can someone give me a code example"

Comment: @musefan: Funny, since there is no question in the post :D.

Comment: @Zeta: yes, I was just getting/editing to that

Comment: Sorry i meant that i know the way but i need some code sample to do that.

Comment: @musefan: Please excuse me. I was asking support to build multi canvas with some code sample through this question  and i got the answer from MarkE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use 2 canvases to support both an indestructible background and a sketching foreground.

BTW, The background doesn't need to be a canvas. It could be just an image or div with content.

**A quick Illustration**

You can wrap your background and sketching canvases in a wrapper div:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <canvas id="canvas2" width=300 height=200></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=200></canvas>
    </div>
```

Then use CSS to position the sketching canvas directly on top of the background canvas:

```
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #wrapper{
        position:relative;
        width:300px;
        height:200px;
    }
    #canvas,#canvas2{
        position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
        border:1px solid green;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    #canvas2{
        border:2px solid red;
    }
```

Here is a small illustration app that uses the background canvas to display a blue background.

The sketching canvas (on top) is used to draw and erase.

Here's code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/G6JAK/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #wrapper{
        position:relative;
        width:300px;
        height:200px;
    }
    #canvas,#canvas2{
        position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
        border:1px solid green;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    #canvas2{
        border:2px solid red;
    }
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas2=document.getElementById("canvas2");
    var ctx2=canvas2.getContext("2d");
    ctx2.fillStyle="skyBlue";
    ctx2.lineWidth=5;
    ctx2.fillRect(0,0,canvas2.width,canvas2.height);

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    var lastX;
    var lastY;

    var mouseX;
    var mouseY;
    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var isMouseDown=false;


    function handleMouseDown(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here
      lastX=mouseX;
      lastY=mouseY;
      isMouseDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseup stuff here
      isMouseDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseOut stuff here
      isMouseDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousemove stuff here
      if(isMouseDown){
          ctx.beginPath();
          if(mode=="pen"){
              ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-over";
              ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY);
              ctx.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
              ctx.stroke();     
          }else{
              ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
              ctx.arc(lastX,lastY,5,0,Math.PI*2,false);
              ctx.fill();
          }
          lastX=mouseX;
          lastY=mouseY;
      }
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

    var mode="pen";
    $("#pen").click(function(){ mode="pen"; });
    $("#eraser").click(function(){ mode="eraser"; });

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <canvas id="canvas2" width=300 height=200></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=200></canvas>
    </div>
    <button id="pen">Pen</button>
    <button id="eraser">Eraser</button>
</body>
</html>
```